# Using detA and detB to calculate the determinant of matrix C

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

If we have C=($A^t$)$^2$BA$^3$B$^-$$^1$A$^-$$^3$ 
and detA=-2 and detB doesnt equal 0, how do we calculate det C?

I know that the transpose of a matrix does not affect the determinant. Does this mean that ($A^t$)$^2$=(-2)$^2$=4?

And then how is A$^-$$^3$ affected? Does this mean the inverse of A cubed? And how does the inverse affect the determinant? Thanks

Comment: You need to repeatedly use the [determinant properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Multiplicativity_and_matrix_groups).

Comment: @vadim123 by using these, i would get C = 4B(-8) $1/B$ $1/(-8)$ am i able to cancel this down to equal 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may recall that, if $\det A \neq 0$, then
$$
\det A{}^t=\det A, \qquad \det (A{}^{p})=(\det A)^p,\quad p=0,\pm 1,\pm2, \ldots.
$$and $$
\det (AB)=(\det A)(\det B)=(\det B)(\det A)=\det (BA)
$$ Thus here:
$$
\det C=\det ( (A^t)^2BA^3B^{-1}A^{-3})=(\det A)^{2+3-3}(\det B)^{1-1}=(\det A)^{2}=4.
$$

Comment: are you allow to reorder the matrices order like that? thank you this answer is clear

Comment: @LaurenBathers When is it about determinants, they are real numbers, so you can reorder... Thanks.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation*}
\det(A^k) = \det(A)^k~\text{and}~\det(A^t) = \det(A)
\end{equation*}

Comment: What does the square at the end mean?

Comment: is there a proof to $det(A^k)=det(A)^k$?

Comment: @gbox yes if you know $det(AB) = det(A)det(B)$

Answer (score 0):

Remember the following

$$\operatorname{det}(AB)=\operatorname{det}{A}\operatorname{det}{B}$$
$$\operatorname{det}{A^n}=(\operatorname{det}{A})^n$$
$$\operatorname{det}{A^T}=\operatorname{det}{A}$$

So in our case we have $B$ and $B^{-1}$ whose determinant cancel out because they are not $0$ (otherwise $B^{-1}$ would not exist) $A^3$  and $A^{-3}$ whose determinant cancel out and we are left with $(\operatorname{det}{A^T})^2=4$